# Migrating Rexster (titan 0.4) Query to Gremlin Server (Titan 1.0) Query

Tags: graph, graph-databases, titan, gremlin, gremlin-server

I am using following Rexster query :

```
 string gremlinQuery = "g.v(" + companyVertexId + ").transform{[salaryInfo:it.outE('Salary'),designationInfo:it.out('Salary')]}";
```

To get the salary information and designation information of particular company using it's `vertexId`.

now I moved to Titan 1.0 and using Gremlin server, i'm stuck and don't know how to create similar query in Gremlin server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transform is not available in gremlin server. 
you can use the following query for getting salaryInfo and designationInfo in one call.

> string gremlinQuery = "g.V(" + companyVertexId + ").as('company').outE('Salary').as('salaryInfo').select('company').out('Salary').as('designationInfo').select('designationInfo','salaryInfo');";

it will return almost same response.

Comment: thanks. with little changes in object structure i was able to get the desired result :)